# Understanding Gcloud Configuration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In awscli, what we do is:-

`aws configure --profile stolencrds`

But I am very confused about how can we configure something like that in `gcloud`. We can take an example like, I was working on my project, and my friend gave his projects service account keys, now I have different keys for two projects, now how can I configure?

Comment: I wrote two articles that will help you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/ AND https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-and-authorizing-service-account-credentials-with-the-cli/

Comment: Hey John, that helps. Thanks for sharing but I have another query, if suppose you found service account .json keys, how are you going to create a new service account with those keys?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "you found a service account JSON key file". The JSON key file represents the service account and includes the private key. If you mean how do you create another service account, that is easy provided the "found" service account has IAM roles granting that privilege. Create a new question as that is a topic to itself.

Comment: Yes! I thought so, will create a new question then, thanks!.